# if submit button clicked modal popup open in middle of display?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My bootstrap modal popup not working when i click submit button..
i can use only bootstrap4, Js, Jquery3.0

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/vo0qcs6h/1/)

```js
function check() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("radio");
  var filled = true;
  var oneChecked = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < inputs; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type === "text" && !inputs[i].value) {
      filled = false;
    }

    if (inputs[i].type === "select" && inputs[i].value) {
      filled = false;
    }

    if (inputs[i].type === "radio" && inputs[i].checked) {
      oneChecked = true;
    }
  }
  if (!oneChecked) {
    filled = false;
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < inputs; j++) {
    if (!inputs[j].value) {
      filled = false;
    }
    if (!inputs[j].oneChecked) {
      filled = true;
    }
  }

  if (filled) {
    document.getElementById("submitacc").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submitacc").disabled = true;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", check);
window.addEventListener("click", check);
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="contactForm">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- From Account name -->
      <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="frm_acc">Select the A/c from which the records are to be transferred:*</label>
        <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="frm_account" id="frm_acc" required>
          <option value="">Choose an items</option>
          <option value="1">Plumz</option>
          <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
          <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
          <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
          <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- To account name -->
      <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="to_acc">Select the A/c to which the records are to be transferred:*</label>
        <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="to_account" id="to_acc" required>
          <option value="">Choose an items</option>
          <option value="1">Plumz</option>
          <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
          <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
          <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
          <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>

  </form>

  <!-- Submit Button -->

  <div class="form-group ml-auto mt-2 mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12 stockform_submit" id="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn add-btn submit-btn disabled" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#merge_err" disabled>Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default reset-btn stock_rst" style="left: 0%" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- modal -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="merge_err">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Error..</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p class="popup-text">Merging option Faild in Transaction record TXN#:XXXXXXX</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-10 pull-right okbutton" id="ok" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
          <!-- onclick="window.location.href='accmaster.html'" -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

im just beginer of coding
This code this code is not working so plz help me

> Any other methos is there?

Example here:

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/vo0qcs6h/
```

[My example link is here](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/vo0qcs6h/1/)

**I just want Enable submit button when form filled and after click submit button modal popup shown**

Comment: Well, on inspect element, there are a lot of errors. Have you tried debugging? `SCRIPT5007: SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: I cant even get your link or snippet to work. Is the `[X]` button important. The only think I recommend you to do is to put `console.log(...usefull diagnostic info...)` everywhere, to make sure that every line of your code is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are writing vanilla JavaScript when you have an option of using jQuery.

Nevertheless, your function check() has many mistakes in it. Primarily being that the input variable is being re-written every time getElementsByTagName is called. I am guessing what you are trying to do is to get all the input, select and radio elements and check whether or not they have values, and accordingly update your filled variable.

getElementsByTagName returns an array of elements.
You can use the ES6 spread operator and forEach to check for inputs that have values.

Check the attached snippet.

```js
function check() {
  var inputs = [...document.getElementsByTagName("input"), ...document.getElementsByTagName("select"), ...document.getElementsByTagName("radio")];

  var filled = false;
  var numberOfFilledInputs = 0;

  inputs.forEach((input) => {
    if (!!input.value) numberOfFilledInputs++;
  });


  if (numberOfFilledInputs === inputs.length) {
    document.getElementById("submitacc").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submitacc").disabled = true;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("keyup", check);
window.addEventListener("click", check);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div>
  <form class="contactForm">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- From Account name -->
      <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="frm_acc">Select the A/c from which the records are to be transferred:*</label>
        <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="frm_account" id="frm_acc" required>
          <option value="">Choose an items</option>
          <option value="1">Plumz</option>
          <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
          <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
          <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
          <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- To account name -->
      <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="to_acc">Select the A/c to which the records are to be transferred:*</label>
        <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="to_account" id="to_acc" required>
          <option value="">Choose an items</option>
          <option value="1">Plumz</option>
          <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
          <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
          <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
          <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </form>
</div>

<!-- Submit Button -->

<div class="form-group ml-auto mt-2 mb-0">
  <div class="col-md-12 stockform_submit" id="">
    <button type="submit" id="submitacc" class="btn add-btn submit-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#merge_err" disabled>Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default reset-btn stock_rst" style="left: 0%" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="merge_err">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Error..</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="popup-text">Merging option Faild in Transaction record TXN#:XXXXXXX</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-10 pull-right okbutton" id="ok" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
        <!-- onclick="window.location.href='accmaster.html'" -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working!! but sir still **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null at check (app.js:409)** this error is shown in other pages

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form class="contactForm">
        <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="frm_acc">Select the A/c from which the records are to be transferred:*</label>
          <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="frm_account" id="frm_acc" required>
            <option value="">Choose an items</option>
            <option value="1">Plumz</option>
            <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
            <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
            <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
            <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
          </select>
          <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- To account name -->
        <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
          <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="to_acc">Select the A/c to which the records are to be transferred:*</label>
          <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="to_account" id="to_acc" required>
            <option value="">Choose an items</option>
            <option value="1">Plumz</option>
            <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
            <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
            <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
            <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
          </select>
          <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn add-btn submit-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#merge_err">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default reset-btn stock_rst" style="left: 0%" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  <div>
</div>

    <div class="modal" id="merge_err">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Error..</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="popup-text">Merging option Faild in Transaction record TXN#:XXXXXXX</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger ml-10 pull-right okbutton" id="ok" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Use JQuery instead of lengthy javascript codes

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 // For Disabling the submit button
  $('.submit-btn').attr('disabled',true);
  $('select').on('change', function() {
    if($('#frm_acc').val() > 0 && $('#to_acc').val() > 0) {
      $('.submit-btn').attr('disabled',false);
    }
  });

  $('.reset-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.submit-btn').attr('disabled',true);
  });

});
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much brw.. and my console is showing errors.. only one error for like **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null
    at check (app.js:409)** this only showing in other pages i dont know why?

Comment: Make sure you have not changed the class of submit button and also make sure that  your reset button is also there and finally don't forget to include  the jquery script tag in the head section